# fetch data from mysql to listview by username

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, listview

I'm doing an android application and the app needs to display all the user's visited places in a listview from Mysql. I can display all the data but I only need the data that the logged-in username marked as his/her visited places. How can I display data by the logged in username? Thank you.

Here is my php script

```
<?php
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

 $jsonData= json_decode($json);

$usr= $jsonData->username;

$strSQL ="SELECT * FROM userbeenthere WHERE username='$usr' ";
mysqli_set_charset($objConnect , 'utf8');

$objQuery = mysqli_query($objConnect, $strSQL);
$arrRows = array();
$arryItem = array();

while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery)){
$arryItem["location"] = $arr["location"];

$arrRows[]= $arryItem;

}
echo json_encode($arrRows);


?>
```

This my ProfDataParser.class

```
public class ProfDataParser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>{
Context c;
String jsonData;
ListView lv;
ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayList<String> beenthere = new ArrayList<>();


    public ProfDataParser(Context c, String jsonData, ListView lv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.jsonData = jsonData;
        this.lv = lv;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute () {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("Parse");
        pd.setMessage("Pasring..Please wait");
        pd.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground (Void...params){
        return this.parseData();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Boolean result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        if (result) {
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(c, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, beenthere);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(c, beenthere.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

private Boolean parseData()

{
    try {
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo;
        beenthere.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jo.getString("location");
            beenthere.add(name);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

and this is my beenthere.class

```
public class beenthere extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textUsername;
final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

final static String urlAddress="http://enyatravel.com/profile/beenthere.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beenthere);

    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_been);
    new ProfDownloader(beenthere.this, urlAddress, lv).execute();

    textUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);

    pref = getSharedPreferences("login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Log.d(TAG, pref.getString("username", ""));

    String username = pref.getString("username", "");
    textUsername.setText(username);


}
}
```

Comment: What data is in the `userbeenthere` table? Is it the place they have been or just a list of places?

Comment: Do you have a flag in your `userbeenthere` table to show if the user has visited there?

Comment: place they have been

Comment: what do you mean by flag?

Comment: Ok so so if the table only contains the places the users have been and you are selecting the rows matching the current users username, I don't see your problem, your code should work.

Comment: There's a problem in fetching data. I only need the data that the loggedin username marked as their visited places and not all the places that was stored un the userbeenthere table.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself, how can the table only contain places the user has been and yet the data in the table contain places the user hasn't been? If the table contains the correct data your code should work. If it does not contain the correct data the problem lies with how you are inserting the data, not querying it.

Comment: You could be requesting with an (objectively) incorrect post body, but I would expect that to result in nothing getting returned at all, or an error in your php.